# UnsatisfiedLinkError - Accessing dll files from jar file

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm developing **Swing** application using **Netbeans**.I'm using the ***dll files*** for my application.
I used the following code. It works perfect in the IDE.

But running from the jar file after clean and build in IDE, it shows following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no win32com in java.l
ibrary.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at test.Test.main(Test.java:78)
```

My code for setting the path..

```
private static void setPath() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("java.library.path", "./lib/win32/");
            Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
            fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
            fieldSysPath.set(null, null);

        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
    }
```

My main method...

```
...
    setPath();
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("win32com");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

And my folder structure..

[image]

Comment: `"./lib/win32/"` is a relative path. So check the current directory. But if you know the path of the library to load you should use `System.load(…)` specifying the actual path instead of hacking the search path for `System.loadLibrary(…)`

Answer (score 0):

For accessing dll files through java code(), One has to do the following

(In my case,for getting **list of comm ports** and establish connection with one of them)

1. Place the dll file (**win32com.dll**) in jre bin folder
2. Place **javax.com.properties** file in the jre lib folder.

Although it works well,but when you export it to a Jar and try to execute the same in other machines,still you have to ensure that the dll and properties files were located at their appropriate places or not.

But,as an Alternate, if you have dll's placed in another location, then you have to set the library path as VM options before exporting to Jar files.

In Netbeans,Click **Project--> Right-click Properties--> Select Run-->** Provide **VM Options** like

```
-Djava.library.path="D:\My Project\lib\win32"
```

*(if dll files are in D:\My Project\lib\win32)*

Also, instead of using **javax.com.properties** file, you can load the driver like

```
   String driverName = "com.sun.comm.Win32Driver";
   CommDriver commdriver = (CommDriver) Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
   commdriver.initialize();
```